# Mongoose $elemMatch How to query both $in and $nin

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose in order to check if an element exist in my DB.

For that I'm using something like-

```js
object.aggregate([
        {$match: {
                "data": {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        $and:[
                            {name: {$in: ["A", "B"]}},
                            {name: {$nin: ["X"]}}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

The problem is text is array. So when I'm getting ["A" , "X"] I wish the result to be empty.

Do you have any ideas?

----------- Edit ------------

Object looks something like:

```js
example1 = { // shouldn't find - not in $in
  _id: "123",
  data: [
      {id:"1",name:"E"},
      {id:"2",name:"R"},
      {id:"3",name:"T"}      
  ]
}

example2 = { // shouldn't find - in both $in $nin
  _id: "456",
  data: [
      {id:"4",name:"A"},
      {id:"5",name:"X"},
      {id:"6",name:"Z"}      
  ]
}

example3 = { // should find - only in $in
  _id: "789",
  data: [
      {id:"7",name:"A"},
      {id:"8",name:"L"},
      {id:"9",name:"Z"}      
  ]
}
```

----------- Edit 2 ------------

Thanks @Anthony For helping me find a better example to the issue.

I think this issue occurs within arrays of array, example:

Data Set

```js
[
  {
    _id: "456",
    data: [
      {
        field: [
          {
            id: "1",
            name: "A"
          },
          {
            id: "2",
            name: "B"
          },
          {
            id: "3",
            name: "Z"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        field: [
          {
            id: "4",
            name: "A"
          },
          {
            id: "5",
            name: "X"
          },
          {
            id: "6",
            name: "Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My solution with element match gets 2 docs: 
([enter link description here](https://mongoplayground.net/))

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      data: {
        $elemMatch: {
          "$and": [
            {
              "field.name": {
                "$in": [
                  "A",
                  "B"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "field.name": {
                "$nin": [
                  "X"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The other solution suggested returns 0 docs:
([enter link description here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fev-EtTLAep))

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$and": [
    {
      "data.field.name": {
        "$in": [
          "A",
          "B"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "data.field.name": {
        "$nin": [
          "X"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: can you post some of your sample collection and the output

Comment: Thanks, I added an example under EDIT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this with simple find query

```
db.collection.find({
  "data": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$and": [
        { "field.name": { "$in": [ "A", "B" ] } },
        { "field.name": { "$nin": [ "X" ] } }
      ]
    }
  }
}, {
  "data": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$and": [
        { "field.name": { "$in": [ "A", "B" ] } },
        { "field.name": { "$nin": [ "X" ] } }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/j2plfio9486)

Comment: The query finds example 2 which should be excluded. I guess because in one element in the array the doc fulfilled the first condition and another array element fulfill the other condition

Comment: @HatzavWolff Please check it here https://mongoplayground.net/p/0Lgkpoiz3SM

Comment: first of all thanks for the playground link, I didn't know this one! For my example you answer is great and I accept it but my real dataset contain another layer which might be the problem. I'm adding example as EDIT 2 - Thank you so much for helping me out!

Comment: I like this solution, using the dot notation combined with $elemMatch.
I think the only problem is that $elemMatch in $projection stage, return only the first occurrence , instead of all the results

Comment: @ChaiHalfon Yes If you want to retrieve all the matched documents then you have to use `$filter` aggregation

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet This is great, Thanks!!