# MongoDB $nin + $elemMatch behaviour

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When trying to do a $nin match with $elemMatch in .net I get no results. I've reconstructed the statement on [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rx4Gcno5ICP).

I guess I'm missing something around the $nin but can't find anything in the docs.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682082/mongoose-elemmatch-how-to-query-both-in-and-nin) is talking about the issue but the solution they gave doesn't work if you set the data up with a valid exclude.

I've read through the docs and a few posts around this issue, I'm assuming there is a gap in my knowledge around how $nin and or $elemMatch works, I hope someone can point me in the correct direction and possible fix the example on mongo playground.

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? Your current playground is working fine as your query is looking for *any* element that is not in ["X"]. So both documents you provided are matched.

Comment: Issue is it returns both the documents not just the one without "X", if you swap to $in it returns the single document. I would expect the $nin to return just the document with "Y".

What I'm trying to get is all documents that don't have a matching element in the array.  The use case is searching for a recipe that doesn't contain "X".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaking the behaviour of `$elemMatch`. `$elemMatch` will return the document if **any** of the array element match your criteria.

For your expected behaviour, you can simply do:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "ingredient.name": {
        $nin: [
          "X"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MhbbJrVuHYJ)